# Frequência média utilizando dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário

Quero consultar a frequência de palavras retornadas em um livro (formato `.txt`) e dividir esta frequência pela quantidade de capítulos encontrados, obtendo assim a média da aparição de palavra por capítulo.

O ponto é que quero retornar esse resultado dentro de um dicionário. Exemplo de retorno esperado:

```
{'casa': 4.9000090}
{'homem': 2.256535434}
```

Já consegui obter o resultado esperado sem utilizar o dicionário como retorno, mas gostaria de concatenar as informações pra ficar da forma acima.

Alguém para indicar qual o melhor caminho?

Meu código está assim:

```
#Código do meu arquivo auxiliar.py que contém as funções de leitura de texto
def abre_texto():
    return open('livroExemplo.txt', 'r')

def consulta_novo_capitulo(line)
    return bool(re.search(r'^Capítulo\s\d\d', line))



#Função principal
import auxiliares as aux

def media_palavras(palavra):
    thisdict = {}
    newChapter = 0
    for line in aux.abre_texto():
        if aux.consulta_capitulo(line) == True:
            newChapter += 1
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in thisdict:
                thisdict[word] = 1
            else:
                thisdict[word] += 1
    print("Existem",newChapter,"capítulos.")
    print("A palavra consultada {",palavra,"} apareceu",thisdict[palavra],"vezes no livro.")
    print("Média de aparição da palavra consultada:",(thisdict[palavra])/newChapter)

media_palavras('casa')
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas se eu tivesse que contar as palavras de um texto eu usaria `collections` e, no final, montaria o dicionario com o resultado, vou dar um exemplo gerando (randomicamente) uma lista de 800 palavras a partir de uma outra lista de apenas 11, vamos considerar que o livro tenha 3 capitulos e que a lista gerada (de 800 palavra) seria o resulado da extração do texto do livro:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

# Palavras das quais será gerada a lista simulando o resultado da extração do texto
palavras = ['madri', 'abrigo', 'fila', 'menino', 'soprano', 'nó', 'engolir',
            'dentro','caverna', 'percepção', 'flash']

# Lista simulando as palavras lidas do texto
livro  = np.random.choice(palavras, 800, replace=True)

# Conta a frequencia de cada palavra na lista
counter = Counter(livro)

# Dicionario vazio para o resultado das médias
medias = {}

# Calculo das médias (considerando 3 capítulos)
for item in counter.items():
  medias[item[0]] = round(item[1]/3,2)

# Apresentando o resultado
print(medias)
```

Saida:

```
{'abrigo': 26.67,
 'menino': 24.33,
 'engolir': 24.67,
 'soprano': 30.0,
 'nó': 24.67,
 'flash': 26.0,
 'dentro': 20.0,
 'percepção': 20.67,
 'fila': 24.67,
 'caverna': 25.0,
 'madri': 20.0}
```

Voce poderá, se quiser, apresentar um dicionario mais completo, que conteria um 'subdicionario' para cada palavra, mostrando a frequencia total e a frequencia média:

```
# Resultado completo
completo = {}
for item in counter.items():
  completo[item[0]] = {'Total':item[1], 'Media': round(item[1]/3,2)}

print(completo)
```

Saida:

```
{'abrigo': {'Total': 80, 'Media': 26.67},
 'menino': {'Total': 73, 'Media': 24.33},
 'engolir': {'Total': 74, 'Media': 24.67},
 'soprano': {'Total': 90, 'Media': 30.0},
 'nó': {'Total': 74, 'Media': 24.67},
 'flash': {'Total': 78, 'Media': 26.0},
 'dentro': {'Total': 60, 'Media': 20.0},
 'percepção': {'Total': 62, 'Media': 20.67},
 'fila': {'Total': 74, 'Media': 24.67},
 'caverna': {'Total': 75, 'Media': 25.0},
 'madri': {'Total': 60, 'Media': 20.0}}
```

Agora é só adaptar ao seu contexto e deverá funcionar.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/collections-counter)